# Windows 10 SDK / Visual Studio: What dependencies are required on target machines?

Tags: visual-studio, clion, windows-10-sdk

I've created a tiny exe file that wraps a 3rd party dll using CLion with Visual Studio 2019 toolchain:

[image]

It works perfectly fine on my laptop. However when I "install" (=copy&paste) the exe file to another machine (Server 2012 R2 and yes I know this is WIn 81. based) it results in an appcrash. On this machine I needed to install Windows 10 SDK (1.2GB) and then it worked. However on another Win 10 machine it simply doesn't work even after installing the Win 10 SDK. This machine runs a never Win 10 version.

I'm completely lost as what the needed dependencies are on the target machines?

EDIT: Also installed newest C++ redistributable on the machine it doesn't work but same issue remains: `exit code -1073741515`

Comment: `-1073741515` = `0xC0000135` = `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` so check the dependencies of both your `.exe` and the 3rd party `.dll`. See for example https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was aware that the error indicated "STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND" but the only dependency (loaded at runtime, not statically linked) from 3rd party was installed on all machines. Hence the issue  was quiet puzzling.

But in the end it was my bad. I took the exe generated by a debug build. If I simply switch to release the exe is only 30 instead of 110kb and it then worked without any issue. I assume the debug build requires some specific Windows SDK / Visual studio dll to be available and hence the error.